# Get AVAudio Recording URL Before App is Terminated

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I've played with several recording apps and when I swipe to dismiss/terminate while recording, when I come back to the app the audio that was recording prior to the app begin terminated, is available for me to listen to. From my understanding that audio is only available via `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording`.

In my app I tried to do the same. If a user is recording audio and the app is suddenly terminated (they swipe it away), I stop the recording. But in the delegate `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording`
I can't seem to get the `url`.

When the app is terminated the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) says we have 5 seconds

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to
> perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before
> time expires, the system may terminate the process altogether.

The `url` usually returns way before 5 seconds but for some reason the recording delegate is never reached. What's the issue? In the example below steps 2 or 5 never get reached.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillTerminate(notification:)),
                                               name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification,
                                               object: nil)

@objc func applicationWillTerminate(notification: Notification) {

     if let micRecorder = micRecorder, micRecorder.isRecording {

         micRecorder.stop() // 1. stop recording
     }
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {

    // 2. print("if successful the url should be returned")

    if flag {

        let url = recorder.url

        // 3. save url to FileManager then to CoreData

    } else {

        // 4. something went awry
    }
}

func audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, error: Error?) {

    // 5. print("something went wrong")

    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Where do you create your `AVAudioRecorder`? Don't you pass it a URL when you create it?

Comment: That's the same url as the one that is returned in the delegate method?

Comment: It should be -- the URL shouldn't change. All you're doing in the delegate method is checking the `url` property of the recorder, which is what gets set in `init`

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, I create it local to the function. For ex. `func startRecording() { let path = NSTemporaryDirectory()... ; let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) ; micRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileURL, settings: myAudioSettings) ; micRecorder?.record() ... }`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, while the recorder is recording, everything is being fed to that fileURL? And once I call micRecorder.stop(), the fileURL will still have the recording irregardless of the delegate method?

Comment: I don't think the delegate method has anything to do with the URL. When you create the recorder, you give it a URL -- that is what's recorded to. If you need a reference to the URL, either store it or make sure you can recreate it.

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't know that. What I was doing is I would take the url from the delegate method, turn it into an asset, then use that as the recording to play back. I thought that was the recordingURL. I'll have to make the fileURL a class level property and see what happens. I have to make several adjustments to my code. I'll try it and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: @jnpdx you was correct, it worked, thanks! Can you post what you said in your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize `AVAudioRecorder`, you pass it a URL. This URL is where the audio data is recorded. That URL will be the same as the URL that you're attempting to get via the delegate methods.

Instead of trying to retrieve the URL via those delegate methods, you can just store the initial URL that you created or just make sure that you can reliably recreate it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Definitely made my life easier!

Comment: One thing I did find out. It makes things more complex. When the user records, stops, records, stops etc etc, I have to initialize the audioRecorder with different URLs otherwise it’ll keep overwriting the same URL and it’ll only record the last thing that they recorded. When this happens the url from the delegate method is works perfectly. However when dismissing the delegate method us still not triggered. I have to keep a separate array of all of those stop and record urls. It’s a tedious process but irregardless your answer helped me figure it all out. THANK YOU!

Comment: Suggestion to (possibly) avoid the above issue -- always record to the same URL. Then, upon completion, move the file somewhere else with a more informative file name (like when the recording was made)

Comment: Interesting. What's the purpose of using the same URL? I let the user stop, record, stop, record ... When using different URLs I notice when I using the delegate method, if the flag is true, I just keep them all in array then use AVMutableMixComposition to turn them all into 1 finished url to listen to using AVAudioPlayer. The way your suggesting, if I use 1 url, at what point do I turn each record/stop to it's own individual url? It seems like it's the same thing because outside of the app termination issue, either way I have to use the delegate method to keep a copy of each recording.

Comment: You would copy the file upon completion of recording (or upon opening the app and realizing that there was a termination and an un-copied file). Too hard to answer specifics beyond that not fully understanding your workflow.

Comment: Np, thanks for taking time to help! Happy Holidays and Happy Coding!!!